# replace text with other using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use replace some text from my url to show url pretty. .Please let me know how can I do it.

for eg. 
        http://example.com/wp-admin
        http://example.com/Market
same I want to replace wp-login
         http://example.com/wp-login
        http://example.com/Market

I'm usign the following code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ – [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !Magic
    RewriteRule .*\.php [F,L]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !Magic
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly. You wish to replace the URL in the browser with another URL. You can do this using a redirect with the redirect flag.

```
Rewrite wp-admin /Market [L,R=302]
Rewrite wp-login /Market [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect the browser to the new URL. The browser will then send a second request with Market as the URL. If it is you intention to serve different pages after the redirect you will have to keep track of the redirect. You could do this using a cookie, with the cookie flag.

```
Rewrite (wp-admin) /Market [L,R=302,CO=from:$1]
Rewrite (wp-login) /Market [L,R=302,CO=from:$1]
```

You could then either rewrite the /Market URL to a PHP script and read-out the cookie from there or do this with mod_rewrite like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} from=wp-admin [NC]
RewriteRule Market /wp-admin [L,CO=from::-1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} from=wp-login [NC]
RewriteRule Market /wp-login [L,CO=from::-1]
```

I hope this helps.

Interesting link: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#modrewrite2